# Using a bitfield for more readable code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm working on a legacy web application written in .NET. At the start of the application it checks for which user type is logged in and determines which UI elements to display based on the user type.

The way this is implemented now is a series of if statements to handle each user type case followed by a function call to set the various UI elements to either visible or invisible based on the user type.  The problem is the function call is kind of messy.  There are about 500 lines of the following:

```
setTabsVisible(true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false);
if (!locked)
{
    setActionButtonsVisibile(true, false, true, "Submit", "");
    script += setTabsReadOnly(false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, true);
    script += setSubTabsReadOnly(true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, false, true);
}
script += setSubTabsVisible(false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, true);
```

All that true, true, false, true, etc isn't very readable at first glance.  To see what's being turned on or off you have to hover over the function and match up boolean values to the parameter list.

So I was thinking a better solution might be a bit field that is built from constants that are bitwise OR'd together.  This way a function call might look more like this:

```
setTabsReadOnly(notesTab | documentsTab | signoffTab | etc);
```

However, C# doesn't seem to have support for bitfields.  Is there a better solution?  Or is it even worth changing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags : short
{
    Foo = 0x1,
    Bar = 0x2,
    Baz = 0x4
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CheckFlags(MyFlags.Bar | MyFlags.Baz);
    }

    public static void CheckFlags(MyFlags flags)
    {
        if (flags.HasFlag(MyFlags.Foo))
            Console.WriteLine("Item has Foo flag set");

        if (flags.HasFlag(MyFlags.Bar))
            Console.WriteLine("Item has Bar flag set");

        if (flags.HasFlag(MyFlags.Baz))
            Console.WriteLine("Item has Baz flag set");
    }
}
```

You should use Flag Enums as the above example shows to Simplify your code. For more infos about Enums, check [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx). So in your case you would have:

```
public static void setTabsReadOnly(YourEnum flags)
{
    // Your Code
} 

setTabsReadOnly(YourEnum.NotesTab | YourEnum.DocumentsTab | YourEnum.SignoffTab);
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to create a `Flags Enum`. You can modify your method to only have a parameter with your enumeration, and then call the method with the enumeration types you want applied:

```
public void MyMethod(MyEnumeration myEnum) { ... }
...
MyMethod(MyEnumeration.First | MyEnumeration.Second | MyEnumeration.Third);
```

Sample from MSDN:

> You can use an enumeration type to define bit flags, which enables an instance of the enumeration type to store any combination of the values that are defined in the enumerator list.

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0x0,
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40
}
class MyClass
{
    Days2 meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> However, C# doesn't seem to have support for bitfields. Is there a better solution?

A [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) enumeration is basically a bitfield.

> Indicates that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field; that is, a set of flags.

```
[FlagsAttribute] 
enum MultiHue : short
{
    Black = 0,
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 4
};

// Black and Red:
MultiHue mh = MultiHue.Black & MultiHue.Red;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to use an Enum with a Flags attribute,

```
[Flags]
enum TabOptions
{
    notesTab = 0x01,
    documentsTab = 0x02,
    signoffTab = 0x04
}
```

You can then OR enum values together in the way you describe.

```
void setTabsReadOnly(TabOptions options)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

setTabsReadOnly(notesTab | documentsTab | signoffTab)